# header('location: ..') not working

Tags: php, apache, http-headers, header

(1)I'm in the process of uploading my website to a remote web server.

(2)The site's template system is set up in a way that all of the pages are formed by sending url-encoded get requests to `index.php`

(3)Loading up the initial page works. This page determines the location of the next page by evaluating the value of its form.

(4)The redirection to the next page is performed by doing a: `header('location: next_page')`

(5)For some reason, the redirection is not performed. Here's what the code looks like:

```
$error = "";
if(isset($_POST['index_choice'])){
    $path_choice = isset($_POST['path']) ? $_POST['path'] : NULL;

    //echo $path_choice;
    //echo $page_inc;

    //nothing after this

    if($path_choice != null){

        if($form->is_connected()){

            //if($path_choice != "" || $path_choice != NULL){
                if($path_choice == "new"){

                    //header('location: /login.php');
                    //header('location: page/login');
                    header('location: /index.php?page=login');
                    exit();

                }
                else{

                    //header('location: /amend.php');
                    //header('location: page/amend');
                    header('location: /index.php?page=amend');
                    exit();
                }
            //}
            /**
            else{
                //destroy_session();
                $error = "You haven't selected a path. Please choose a path";
            }
             *
             */
        }
        else{
            //destroy_session();
            $error = "Problems with connecting to the database";
        }
    }else{
        //destroy_session();
        $error = "You have not indicated your choice";
    }

}
```

**SOLVED**

It was a matter of having a blank space after a `?>` somewhere else in the code. This was revealed to me after placing the following commands at the top of the code:

```
 error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
```

I'd like to say thanks to all of the people that have tried to help.

Comment: "It was a matter of having a blank space after a ?> somewhere else in the code." - a good reason to leave off the PHP closing tag at the end of the .php file if you can. Thus avoiding whitespace issues.

Answer (score 16):

Looks like you're echo-ing text to the browser before sending the header('location'). 
You can not send content to your browser before executing a header(), as your echo will force a header to be sent. Comment these lines out and see if it works:

```
// echo $path_choice;
// echo $page_inc;
```

Now your header will be sent and you will be redirected.

Comment: @Karst Lok 

That looks like the right answer, and I've done what you've suggested. However, it hasn't changed any thing.

Comment: Try adding the complete address including http:// / https:// And if you want to do it by the book, you have to write Location with a capital L

Comment: @Karst Lok: HTTP header names are case-insensitive per RFC 2616.

Comment: @Karst Lok Using the full address doesn't do any thing.

Comment: What's higher up in your code? Is there any blank space before the opening `<?php`? Anything in your error log?

Answer (score 14):

**add** this code to **first** of code:

```
<?php
ob_start();
?>
```

Answer (score 8):

You can try the javascript way of redirecting the page:

```
echo '<script>window.location = "'.$url.'";</script>';
```

Comment: I noticed that some plugins verbose too early, screwing any call to header. In this case, using a JS makes the trick effectively.

Answer (score 4):

Just try this. it will work

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>  window.location='index.php'; </script>";
```

instead of  `header("location: index.php");`

Comment: This is so messy :p And it takes pretty long to refresh

Answer (score 2):

Does simple PHP script like the following work?

```
<?php header('Location: /index.php?page=login'); ?>
```

You also have to make sure that the code path with `$path_choice != null` and `$form->is_connected() === true` is actually taken because your error states don't set HTTP headers at all.

Comment: Now make sure that the correct code paths are taken in your script. Although that's more a question for StackOverflow rather than ServerFault.

Comment: It worked.  Actually I was missing / before index.php. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

I see a 'destroy_session()', are you using session_start() somewhere?
Make sure that NO content (including (session)cookies) is already sent.

Tips for debugging: set error_reporting(E_ALL) (including E_NOTICE).
That'll give you the line on which the headers are sent.

Other sources of trouble:
- [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte-order_mark)
- extra lines before  in an included file

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to check your if-stack and make sure you are getting into each of your loops. Place an echo after each if statement to make sure the header() is even being evaluated, your loop is prolly being cut earlier than you expect.

My suspect has to do with the usage of null and $path_choice != null. Have you tried is_null() or isset() since they were designed specifically to check if a variable is null. Also, the !== operand may work in this case too, but i'm not sure offhand if PHP has that.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure before `<?php` of the php file you dont have a space. It might help if you changed the file encoding type to UTS_8 without BOM and backspace just before `<?php` and make sure you dont have `session start()` after anything in the file. It should be just after

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure before your php code you do not have a space because this does matter.

For example

```
<?php
some code this is the correct way
?>

--------------

<?php
some code this is the incorrect way the space above matters
?>
```

Comment: I've edited the answer to show the code, however it doesn't seem to show what you want it to. Please review my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you tried everything, this example can help (HTML/PHP):

```
<?php
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
    echo '<html>
            <head>
                <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0;url=http://www.url.com/index.php?code=404" />
            </head><body></body>
          </html>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there should be no whitespace at the beginning of your code

Eg:

```
------whitespace----
<?php
.
.
.
. ?>
```

Remove space from first line such that `<?php` must be in first line.