# PHP If Else statement not redirecting correctly?

Tags: php, mysql, session, if-statement

I'm trying to create an if else statement to say that if a user isn't logged in send him to the homepage, otherwise, he can go to dashboard.php

```
// Check to see if user is logged in
if ($_SESSION['kt_login_id'] == '') {
    header( 'Location: index.php' );
} else if ($_SESSION['kt_login_id'] != '') {
    header( 'Location: dashboard.php' );
};
```

In firefox I receive an error however saying this page is trying to redirect in a way that isn't possible?

Comment: ok where did you have put this?did you had use `session_start();` before if else?

Comment: header needs a full URL to redirect,

see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519807/header-location-not-working-properly

Comment: Just so you know, it's redundant to state the boolean negation of the `if` condition in the `else` condition. If `if` does not apply, `else` will apply automatically.

Comment: What happens if you specify the full url, instead of only the file (i.e. `http://www.mysite.com/index.php`)?

Comment: If, for example, your page is dashboard.php, and you are checking in it, the code above, you will cause an infinite loop. because the elseif statement everytime will try to redirect to the same page

Comment: Seem that the trouble in your $_SESSION['kt_login_id'] value

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you've already written content to the page

[How to make a redirect in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php) states that

You can use the header() function to send a new HTTP header, but this must be sent to the browser before any HTML or text (so before the  declaration, for example).

Answer (score 0):

Try using isset

```
[code]


session_start();
 // Check to see if user is logged in
if  (isset ($_SESSION['kt_login_id'] )) {  
header( 'Location: dashboard.php' );
} else {
header('Location: index.php);
}


[\code]
```