# PHP header location absolute URL

Tags: php

I came across an issue where an absolute path set in header location wouldn't work but pointing to the file itself did. This only affected a few customers. One of them was nice enough to try connecting through a VPN which made the header location work.

Didn't work:

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
```

Works:

```
header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
```

Can anyone shine some light on this?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3520193/2229404) could shine some light?

Comment: The one that doesn't work is actually correct. As for why it doesn't work - did you maybe gather any info on which browser produced the fault?

Comment: Yes, tried 3 different browser, tablet, cell phone. None worked. Connected through VPN, worked instantly.

Comment: Can everyone reach the http://www.example.com (or whatever it actually is) URL? Or just over the VPN? Is the URL reachable outside of your local network?

Comment: It works fine for 99% of the customers.

Answer (score 1):

Your affected customers are not able to resolve the http://www.example.com (or whatever it actually is) URL for some reason. You can verify this by having them just try and visit the http://www.example.com by manually typing it in the browser location bar. That should fail too.

This can happen you have a site that is available under a number of domains, or directly by the IP address. Even www / non-www versions can make this happen. They hit the site at one domain or IP address that works for them, and then you try and redirect them to a URL they can not resolve. This explains why redirecting to just the path works, but an absolute URL doesn't.

If they **can** reach http://www.example.com in the browser, but not by redirect, ask them to blow out the browser cache.

Comment: _especially_ with the mentioning of it working over VPN this is most likely the answer (which can caused by either a DNS problem, routing problems, or incorrect firewall settings at the servers side). If those aren't it (and my main reason for commenting): I experienced this problem recently with virtual machines under libvirt version 0.8X (denying access to seemingly random IPs, but consistently for only those IPs), for which an upgrade to 1.* of libvirt fixed the problem.

Comment: My thoughts exactly; the "works over VPN" part is what solidified it for me. As for the *reason* why some folks cant hit the URL, I purposely didn't elaborate, but you are correct in that it could be any number of things.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Cache had been cleared many times and the problem remained.

Comment: Where do you guys suggest at look first? I am out of ideas.

Comment: Can the affected users reach the URL manually in a browser? What URL/IP are they using before the header redirect fails? Don't assume, check with them.

Answer (score 0):

Also always exit the script afterwards because otherwise in my experience in certain circumstances code that comes after the redirect might still be executed. So a good example would look like this:

```
header("location:http://www.example.com/path/to/myfile.php");
exit;
```

Often you would use a server variable for this case:

```
$url = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]."/path/to/myfile.php";
header("location:".$url);
exit;
```

Cheers!

Link answer: https://tousu.in/qa/?qa=1091514/